# Three adults staying in a room that says two adults on the reservation

Tags: legal, bookings, hotels, spain

A friend and I have booked a package holiday in Spain later this year. I have one more friend that wants to join us as he can get booked on the same flight. But the reservation is for only two adults, not three. On the booking it says the room sleeps 3 and has a pull out sofa bed. Do you think he will be alright (6 nights) if we take his bag upstairs for him on the first day and he comes up to the room 3 minutes after or before we do throughout our stay or will he get caught and if we do get caught what will happen?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I believe this was previously covered at *[Can a hotel kick you out if you let an unregistered guest share a room with you?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22285)* You may also be interested in *[Why does hotel price change with more occupants?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90472)*

Comment: Have you checked the T&C of your booking? IMHO it’s highly unlikely this plan is permitted. On a practical note I’d expect that no linen/towels will be supplied in the room for a third person even if there is a sofa bed, and your friend will have to spend the entire holiday sneaking in and out; if you’re caught you’ll very probably be asked to pay the extra and worse case scenario your friend could be asked to leave. You should contact the holiday company and ask to change the booking.

Comment: Lodgings vary widely: some won't care (and may not even be able to see) who comes to your room, while others will care a lot and raise a ruckus. Without having experience of that particular place, it's pretty hard to guess.

Comment: There is likely an extra charge for the third guest, for linens, and likely breakfast, usually included in Spain.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus, I don't think breakfast is "usually included". My experience is that it is usually cheaper and nicer to tick the no breakfast option, and find a nearby cafe.